# Android Real Time Multiplayer issues

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I integrated in some of my Android games real time multiplayer using google play games services. Everything worked fine until last week.

I think the last Google Play Services update messed up something. Sometimes when I try to `sendReliableMessage` the message is not sent, or not delivered. If the status code is different from `OK`.

I try to send last message again and again but it just wont send. And after a few minutes of trying to send the last message one of the players is dropped from the room.

I suspect that the problem is not exactly in sending the message but in disconnecting one of the players in the middle of the game.

Does anyone experience the same problem? This happens on multiple games and only since last Monday.

A few weeks ago the multiplayer system had a problem and people couldn't create a multiplayer room and Google fixed it after a few days but is it possible that they messed up something else? I don't have a logcat code because I test on real devices. When the game stops I don't even know who is the dropped player. They are both in the room but the reliable messege is not sending sometimes and this messes up the whole game. Anyone using Play Games and have the same problem?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I'm using the code from here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

Comment: Organized your question for better readability

Comment: I used to have similar issues with C++ version, what I did to make things easier on my side was to create a small console like window in the corner of my game (scroll view) and I would push every network activity in that console, so I could monitor what was happening in my "game layer" persay.